# How to filter only the Brand in my custom adapter without using Viewholder?

Tags: android

I'm creating an Android application that has a custom listview and a custom listview adapter. How can I filter only the brandname using a custom listview adapter without using viewholder? Is it possible? If it is, how can I filter it?

Listviewadapter.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView Brand;
    TextView Category;
    TextView Code;
    TextView Description;
    TextView Price;
    TextView Availability;
    ImageView Image;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);

    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    Brand = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Brand);
    Category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Category);
    Code = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Code);
    Description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Desscription);
    Price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Price);

    // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
    Image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    Brand.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.Brand));
    Category.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.Category));
    Code.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.Code));
    Description.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.Description));
    Price.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.Price));
    // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
    // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.Image), Image);
    // Capture ListView item click

    Availability = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Availability);
    if(Availability.getText().equals("Available")){

        Availability.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

    }
   return itemView;
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing any information filtering within the listviewadapter but rather in the main class and then transmit to your listviewadapter the information after it has been processed

This is mine and what I do is just

```
 public class LVAAdjust extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public LVAAdjust(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void ListViewAdapter2(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {

    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;
    TextView txtThree;
}


private int selectedItem;

// is used outside the adapter for example OnItemClickListener
public void setSelectedItem(int position) {
    selectedItem = position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adjustcols, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.TextFirst);
        holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.TextSecond);
        holder.txtThree = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.TextThree);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> map = data.get(position);


  String fir = (map.get(FIRST_COLUMN) == null) ?
  "NA" :     map.get(FIRST_COLUMN);
    String sec = (map.get(SECOND_COLUMN) == null) ?
   "NA" : map.get(SECOND_COLUMN);
    String thi = (map.get(THIRD_COLUMN) == null) ? 
  "NA" : map.get(THIRD_COLUMN);
    try {
                holder.txtFirst.setText(fir);
    holder.txtSecond.setText(sec);
    holder.txtThree.setText(thi);
    holder.txtFirst.setHeight(40);
    holder.txtFirst.setTextSize(18);

    holder.txtSecond.setHeight(40);
    holder.txtSecond.setTextSize(18);

    holder.txtThree.setHeight(40);
    holder.txtThree.setTextSize(18);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }


    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Please give me example

Comment: please help me i want to filter only the brandname

Comment: You should process the list and then add it to the adapter to display properly

Comment: I get your point but im new in android development i do not know how to implement it , Can you help me on how to do it properly?